# Accessing instance vars and methods from a c function

Tags: objective-c, chipmunk

In Objective-C, is it possible to access instance variables and methods from within the scope of a static c function?  I feel like there is probably a simple answer to this that I'm overlooking, but I'm still fairly new to this language.

Consider the following stripped down code:

```
@implementation MyObject

static int ammoHitSensor(cpArbiter *arb, cpSpace *space, void *unused)
{
    // Call an instance method - doesn't work, self is undefined!
    [self doSomethingElse];
}

-(id)init
{
    // Code to create graphics, etc, hidden for clarity 
    // Adding a collision handler in the Chipmunk physics library
    cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler(space, COL_TYPE_AMMO, COL_TYPE_SENSOR, ammoHitSensor, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

-(void)doSomethingElse
{
    // Stuff happens
}

@end
```

So I guess once I get into the scope of `ammoHitSensor`, I'm hoping there is some way to get back into the scope of `MyObject`. So far I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `self` along when you call that C function. C functions don't have `self` or `_cmd` since they don't live inside objects (regardless of where you put them in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static int ammoHitSensor(cpArbiter *arb, cpSpace *space, void *obj)
{
    [(MyObject*)obj doSomethingElse];
}

-(id)init
{
    cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler(space, COL_TYPE_AMMO, COL_TYPE_SENSOR, ammoHitSensor, NULL, NULL, NULL, self);
}
```